# How to parse the following から and is the もとで a noun?

Tags: usage, parsing, nouns

The following sentence appears on a [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BW6iZ.jpg) in my book:

> 悪夢**から**一夜明け、アインの**もとで**訓練を重ねる日々が始まった。

I think the above から has the meaning of "after"; but the suspicious possibility of the から being a questioning か with the suffix of ら niggles at the back of my mind. So I must ask, is it parsed as から or is it a questioning か + ら suffix?

**Secondary Example of ら-Suffix**

> (Found on [Jishio.org](https://jisho.org/search/ra))
>
> 諸君**ら**のたゆまぬ努力と労働によって、ついに我らがアジトが完成した！！

[Jishio.org](https://jisho.org/search/%E4%B8%8B) has various definitions on もと, however; I decided the following definition of もと is the most applicable to my sentence based on context (アイン**のもとで**訓練 = ...training under Ein...):

> Noun
>
> 1. under (guidance, supervision, rules, the law, etc.)​often のもとに or のもとで

Is the reason the dictionary claims のもとで/もと is a noun because the given definition of "under" can be loosely considered a 'place' in the physical direction sense, or is it a cross-language-barrier issue (I.E. considered a noun in one language but not the other)?

Comment: `ら prefix` -- ってどんなのですか？　Could you give an example?

Comment: @Chocolate Typo there, but for a example of a ら suffix look at this example sentence I found and will be adding as a second example to my question: 諸君らのたゆまぬどりょく努力とろうどう労働によって、ついにわれ我らがアジトがかんせい完成した！！

Comment: 「諸君ら」「我ら」の「ら」ね・・・ It's a plural suffix so don't you expect it to appear at the end of a noun?

Comment: @Chocolate Yep, I figured the から wasn't a 'か + ら suffix', but the doubt still niggled at the back of my head. Seems to have stopped with its niggling at the moment, hopefully it will stay that way for the next week or so.

Comment: `because "under" can be loosely considered a "place" in the physical direction sense, or is it a cross-language-barrier issue` <-- Sorry, I don't really understand. Which way would you consider these→「の下に」(under),「の上に」(on),「の横に」(by/beside),「の近くに」(near),「の後で」(after),「の前に」(before), or「のために」(for), etc...?

Comment: @Chocolate "のもとで  under (guidance, supervision, rules, the law, etc.)​" as I block quoted above my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101417/discussion-between-toyu-frey-and-chocolate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 悪夢**から**一夜明け、アイン**のもとで**訓練を重ねる日々が始まった。

The から is a 助詞(particle), meaning "after~" (or "from~" "since~").

(The plural suffix ら should be attached to a noun or pronoun.)

---

> Is the reason the dictionary claims のもとで/もと is a noun

I don't think they claim のもとで is a noun. They're saying もと (下) is a noun, and that ～のもとで can be used to mean "under~~".

I think you could think of it like this:

「～の+もと+で」 *lit.* "at + the foot + of~" → "under~"

Compare:
「～の+前+で」 *lit.* "at + the front + of~" → "before~"
「～の+そば+で」 *lit.* "at + the proximity + of~" → "by / beside~"
「～の+ため+に」 *lit.* "for + the sake + of~" → "for~"
(前、そば、ため are nouns.)